# String in array returning undefined only when trying to get single value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, roblox

soo doing console.log on the table works but when i try to get a single value it returns undefined like this [undefined: "text"] and the second for loop variable is always 5 for some reason. i don't know how to reproduce this.
groupCache and shoutCache are empty arrays

```
//userid, groupCache, shoutCache defined above

function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    if(arr1.length !== arr2.length)
        return false;
    for(i = arr1.length; i--;) {
        if(!arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]))
            return false;
        }

    return true;
}

setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.roblox.com/users/" + userid + "/groups").done(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (!arraysEqual(data, groupCache)) {
                groupCache.push(data[i].Id.toString())
            }
        }
        for (var v = 0; v < groupCache.length; v++) {
            $.get("https://web.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=" + groupCache[v]).done(function (dataA) {
                var elems = $(dataA);
                var finda = $('#ctl00_cphRoblox_GroupStatusPane_StatusTextField', elems);
                shoutCache[groupCache[v]] = finda.text() // does not work
                console.log(groupCache[v] + " :GC")
                console.log(shoutCache)
            })
        }
    })
}, 10000);
```

Manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["/libs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "/scripts/Notify.js"]
    },
    "name": "Extension",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Extension"
    }, 
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "options.html",
        "img/*.png",
        "JSON/*.json"
    ],
    "options_ui": {
        "page": "options.html",
        "chrome_style": true
    },
    "permissions": ["storage", "background"],
    "short_name": "Extension",
    "version": "0.1.0"
}
```

Comment: async calls in a for loop?

Comment: Yes ...........

Comment: ? .............

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of any "js asynchronous loop" question.

Answer (score 0):

The single item issue is a hint that you have something similar to an Out of Bounds error going on. I see that your for loop starts at the length of the string (Remember that the length of the string is always one more than the last index of a string), so you should make the following change:

```
function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    if(arr1.length !== arr2.length)
        return false;
    for(var i = arr1.length - 1; i--;) {
        if(!arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]))
            return false;
        }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is not my issue shoutCache[groupCache[v]] = finda.text() is i commented it with //does not work

Comment: My bad. I guess I was just thinking that if the arraysEqual function didn't work then the condition for pushing the data to the groupCache wouldn't be satisfied which would cause the array to remain empty. Sorry but that's the only idea I've got. Good luck!